# How to split string by first occurrence of a char (:) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

I have got following two strings:

```
1. 'TestKey : TestValue'
2. '"Test : Key" : Test:Value'
```

Here I want to split both strings by the first occurrence of the char colon (:) and I have to ignore the colon if the string part is enclosed with double quotes.

I have to split the first string as like below:

```
[TestKey, TestValue]
```

And need to split the second string like below:

```
[Test : Key, Test:Value]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in JavaScript with or without Regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to split first and check the double quotes in every set of data anf if not found add them though join.

```
var str = '"Test : Key" : Test:Value';
var arr = str.split(':');
var newArr = [];
var ktr = '';
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
 if(arr[i].indexOf('"') !== -1) {
   ktr += arr[i] + ':';
 } else {
    newArr.push(arr[i]);
 }
}
if(ktr !== '') {
  ktr = ktr.substring(0,ktr.length-1);
  newArr.unshift(ktr);
}
console.log(newArr.join(':'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of working code using a RegExp testing the strings you provided as examples:

```
var regex = /\"{0,1}([^"]*)\"{0,1}\s:\s\"{0,1}([^"]*)\"{0,1}/g;
var str1 = 'TestKey : TestValue';
var str2 = '"Test:Key" : Test:Value';
var str3 = '"Test : Key" : Test:Value';

var firstArray = regex.exec(str1);
regex.lastIndex = 0; //reset the regex

var secondArray = regex.exec(str2);
regex.lastIndex = 0; //reset the regex

var thirdArray = regex.exec(str3);
regex.lastIndex = 0; //reset the regex

//remove the first element of each array, which is the whole string
firstArray.shift();
secondArray.shift();
thirdArray.shift();
```

Hope it helps.

You can test the RegExp here: https://regex101.com/r/PV123v/1